# Do not allow upgrades with WiX installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX installer for which I don't want to allow upgrades. Instead, I want the user to get a message saying that an existing version is already installed that they should uninstall that first.

I've looked at the [WiX documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/), but can't see how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add `Disallow="yes"` to the MajorUpgrade element:

```
<MajorUpgrade Disallow="yes" DisallowUpgradeErrorMessage="Cannot upgrade - uninstall existing installation first" />
```